# How to prevent pip from installing to venv/local/bin?

Tags: python, pip

Normally, installing a Python package with `pip` installs it to `<venv>/bin`. However, I've recently been seeing it installing some executables to `<venv>/local/bin`, which isn't included by default in PATH by the activate script, making them inaccessible.

I could manually change the PATH in `<venv>/bin/activate` to include `<venv>/local/bin`, but that feels like a hack, and that the proper solution would be to figure out why it's installing into the wrong directory.

Why is it doing this, and how do I fix it?

I'm using Python 3.10 on Ubuntu 20.04.

Answer (score -1):

I have been facing the same issue with tox (which launches virtualenv) under Ubuntu 22.04 LTS (WSL2). I solved it by removing **~/.cache** and **~/.local** folders.

```
rm -fr ~/.cache && rm -fr ~/.local
```

Comment: It's not safe to remove the `~/.local` directory. many applications are using it.